# Custom protocol in hyperlinks on mediawiki site

Tags: mediawiki

We have custom protocol on our network that opens up windows in our application. We would like to put links to this application in our Wiki however the only protocols mediawiki seems to recognise are http:// file:// ftp://.

We have put a fudge in that passes a parameter to a html file and executes a link, however it would be great if anyone knew a way of having custom protocol hyperlinks in mediawiki sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use $wgUrlProtocols in your LocalSettings.php.

See here for instructions: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/$wgUrlProtocols

Comment: Thank you, quite annoyed at myself for not finding that myself.